# Angular 8 Async Pipe subscription issue

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular8, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-8.0

Full StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular8-async-pipe

There are three identical components in app component template:

```
<app-loader></app-loader>
<app-progress></app-progress>
<app-spinner></app-spinner>
```

Every component dispatches it's own NgRx action, which fires an Http request using NgRx effects and waits for its completion:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ActionsService } from '../../../services/actions.service';

import * as MockyActions from '../../actions/mocky.actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-spinner',
  templateUrl: './spinner.component.html'
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit {
  progress$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor (
    private store: Store<any>,
    private actionsService: ActionsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.progress$ = this.actionsService
      .isInProgress(MockyActions.GetMockySpinner)
      .pipe(
        map(({status}) => status),
        tap((status) => console.log('GetMockySpinner: ', status))
      );

    this.store.dispatch(MockyActions.GetMockySpinner());
  }
}
```

In every component using Async Pipe I want to show spinner while Http request is in progress:

```
<div class="text-center" *ngIf="!(progress$ | async); else progress">
  Spinner
</div>

<ng-template #progress>
  <div class="text-center">
    <span class="spinner spinner-sm"></span>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

But only spinner in `<app-spinner></app-spinner>` component is displaying during Http request progress in this case. And if the sequence of components in app component template changed:

```
<app-loader></app-loader>
<app-progress></app-progress>
<app-spinner></app-spinner>
<app-loader></app-loader>
```

Spinner in `<app-loader></app-loader>` component is displaying during Http request progress in this case. So only last component in template works as expected.

So what's changed with Async Pipe in Angular 8 or what I'm doing wrong?

Full StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular8-async-pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using an actual state and reducer for your app. NgRX requires that you use both actions and reducers. The problem you are having is that by the time the first two components have subscribed to the actions subject, it is the third action that is there. You don't listen for actions to occur in NgRX. What you do instead is watch for your state to be modified by the action.

Here is a working stackblitz that fixes your issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular8-async-pipe-xexehj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Below is some helpful documentation.
https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers
https://ngrx.io/guide/store

Comment: Of course it's working fine with reducers, but this example is a small version of a big app. And before this update from Angular 7 and NgRx 7 to 8th version this approach worked fine. And we have to do a lot of work to move all progress statuses from components to reducers.

Comment: The issue is that because you are subscribing to your progress indicators inside the template and emitting the action in your ngOninit, the action is being sent to the store before you are subscribing to watching for it. Because the ActionsSubject is a BehaviorSubject, you are getting the last action only for all of your items. You can see that in this stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular8-async-pipe-hxwk6t). You can fix it by subscribing in ngOninit like here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular8-async-pipe-zgteve)

Comment: Yes, the same approach with subscribing is used now to fix this problem in App. But it worked fine in 7th version of Angular and NgRx. So what was the changes from 7th version to 8th version to break this behavior?

Comment: I am not completely sure. If I had to make a guess, I would assume that in Angular 7 and before, the renderer linked new components and called their ngOnInit immediately, but in 8, that was changed to link child components in one run of the microtask loop, and to call ngOnInit in another run.

Comment: Seems to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your `MockyActions`.

Change

```
this.progress$ = this.actionsService.isInProgress(MockyActions.GetMockyProgress)
...
```

and

```
this.progress$ = this.actionsService.isInProgress(MockyActions.GetMockyLoader)
...
```

To

```
this.progress$ = this.actionsService.isInProgress(MockyActions.GetMockySpinner)
```

and you example works fine.

Comment: Yes, it's working fine with one action. But in our app we need to show spinners for different actions in different components on the page. And every MockyAction works fine. So the problem is not in actions declaration.